# Ionic: Enable scroll in inset list

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

Is there a way to achieve scrolling of a list (`ion-list`)  which is inside a `DIV` element so that it does not occupy whole screen? As shown on the image bellow:

[image]

For example list in a modal window is "scroll-able", but I cannot find a key to enable scrolling the list inside `<div class=my-inset>`.

List:

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <div class=my-inset>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
        Item {{ item.id }}.
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Css:

```
.my-inset{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: solid;
}
```

[CodePen example.](http://codepen.io/MichalFoksa/pen/mAVbdN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I could recommend would be to change your CSS Overlay property on your .my-inset class. To fix it, I applied an overlay-x and overlay-y instead of just a single overlay, and set the overlay-y to "scroll". `overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;`

I hope that helps!

Comment: Nice - this actually answers the question. Do you know how to keep the functionality, but hide the scroll bar?

Comment: There is a nice answer regarding this already, so I'd recommend taking a look at that as it answers it better than I would be able to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll